# How to open Lightning carousel image href link in new tab?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a carousel component, when we click on image it should open in new tab. But with standard functionality it is opening in same window. I tried using onclick function but it is not working. How to pass url value from component to java script controller?

```
<lightning:carousel disableAutoScroll="false">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.recordList}" var="l">
                        <lightning:carouselImage src = "{!l.image__c}" 
                        header = "{!l.Header}" description = "{!l.Description}" 
                        alternativeText = "{!l.AlterText}" onclick={!c.onClick} id="{!l.imgurl__c}">
                        </lightning:carouselImage>
                    </aura:iteration>
                  </lightning:carousel>
```

Controller.js:

```
onClick: function(component, event, helper){
alert('onclick called'); // this is working
var urlval = event.target.Id;// this and window.open is not working
window.open(urlval, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275968/how-to-open-a-url-in-new-tab-from-lightning-component/275995#275995) is the way to do it. However, as you are not getting `recordList` , [edit] the question to ask about that issue. Show relevant code - how are you trying to get that value? What have you tried so far? where are you blocked? any other info useful?

Comment: @salesforce-sas I edited my question, I need solution to open my url in new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not HTML element, and it is `lightning` base component, it will expose only [secured versions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) and so `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` **May not** always give the element. `lightning:carouselImage` is not exposing the target directly.

1. To get the element you should use `event.getSource()` .
2. Also, you should get `id` and not `Id`

You can use below method:

```
onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    var urlval = event.getSource().get("v.id");
    window.open(urlval, '_blank');
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working now. :)